# How to set JwtBearerOptions after calling function AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerScheme, o => { }); with empty opts in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, webapi

I'm using `Asp.net Core 3.1`. While creating a new web project using Visual Studio we select `API` template and Change Authentication to `Individual User Accounts` and configure `Azure ADB2C` options and finally create the project.

In our generated `Startup.cs` file, we have following function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

The implementation of `AddAzureADB2CBearer()` can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs). This implementation has a line of code is as follows:

```
builder.Services.Configure(scheme, configureOptions);
    builder.AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerScheme, o => { });
```

In the above line, its adding `JwtBearer` with empty `JwtBearerOptions`. And Authentication is working perfect. But I want to set some `JwtBearerOptions` after the following line of code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
   .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

Is there any way to configure those options after executing the above two lines? I tried the following lines but nothing worked.

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(options =>
{
     options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
     };

     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidAudience = "myAudience"
      };
});
```

Please note that I can use `AddJwtBearer` function and pass options after setting them. But I want to use Microsoft default implementation. And just need to update my `JwtBearerOptions` that was passed to `AddJwtBearer` as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to override the specific schema after `AddAzureADB2CBearer`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "myAudience"
    };
});
```